# How do I move a Realm object to a global scope

Tags: swift2, realm

I am building an app using Swift2 and Realm to persist the data.  The data relationships could be described as parent-to-child-to-grandchild objects.  Each object has it's own subclass written with the same format.  I am getting the runtime error "RLMObject subclasses cannot be nested within other declarations. Please move _TtCC12 ... to global scope.'" on the grandchild object.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the declarations of your `RealmSwift.Object` subclasses must be at the outermost scope, and cannot be nested within other class or struct declarations, or function definitions.

Comment: Thanks bdash.  I found the offending code thanks to the answer you gave.

Comment: Do you have explanation why is this the case?

Comment: I put an instance of let _ = try! Realm() in my AppDelegate, then re-referenced it in another class, and I got the same error...class is global/not subclassed...